# Is it possible to run automated text-replacement script after heroku deployment?

Tags: heroku

Currently, I have a web app with a config file. The config file has global declaration for variables such as `domain_name`, `redis_url`, etc. However, when users deploy the app on their heroku account, they will have to manually change these settings to match their environments. Is it possible to make heroku runs a post-deployment script that replace these settings with heroku properties?

Answer (score 0):

Starting point would be [Heroku Environment Variables](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars) which your app is probably using already. If not, then I strongly advise to do so.

Then I see two options depending on config file type:

If config file is **script file** it can read environment variables directly and problem is solved.

If config file is **text file** it must be generated first. You can achieve that by creating a generator script you put in your app repo. For purpose of this explanation let's assume that your web app is Python based. You can create file `bin/generate_config.py` and add it to repo. Then in this generator you read variables form system and create text config file.
Next all you need to do is to modify your `Procfile`. Let's assume it looks like this:

`web: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:${PORT}`

you need to change it to:

`web: python bin/generate_config.py & python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:${PORT}`

It will first generate config file, and then start your app.

You'll have to adopt my solution to your web app language but general idea is the same.

I hope this helps you a bit.